# How to test a USB cable?

Tags: usb, cable-tester

So bear with me, as I have a very limited knowledge of electronics.

I cut an old USB cable and tinned the wires so I can test them.

I know on a USB cable the red and black wires are 5V and ground. The other two are for data. I can easily test the 5V and ground with a multimeter, but how could I test the other two to see if they're working?

Can you even test those? Can you use a multimeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a lot of experience doing that and the best way to test it is to connect both ends to something and see if they work. You cannot use a multimeter to test the two data wires, because multimeters test how much electricity passes through. Hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to test all the wires with a multimeter.  This site talked about a similar project, and he suggested plugging in a mouse to see if it works. http://www.androidcentral.com/weekend-project-diy-usb-go-old-cables.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can test using the Ohmmeter setting of a multimeter.

With the probes not touching anything it should read infinite. Touch the probes to each other and it should read zero.

Touch the probes to the two ends of the cable. Should read zero (or VERY low resistance)

That will tell you if there is a break in the cable